# linux Environment vars permanently added using python

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables

I am trying to update a linux environment variable using a bash script, loaded from a python script

1.- I delete it:

```
del os.environ['USER']
```

2.- I run sourced the bash script with commands lib:

```
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput('. ' + PATH +'/script.sh')
```

2.1.- status = 0; output = 'Environment var updated'

So.. until here, everything seems to works ok

3.- But when I try to test that the var is alredy updated:

```
print os.environ['USER']
```

I get the following output:

```
KeyError: 'USER'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.environ` is *not* your environment, but a representation of it, created when the `os` module is imported for the first time. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters) some platforms will reflect changes to `os.environ` in the process's environment. Since you run a subprocess to change the environment, those changes are made to the *subprocess*, not to the process in which your Python code runs.

There is no way to have changes to a process's environment reflected in its parent process's environment.

Answer (score 1):

The environment is inherited by a child process from its parent; more specifically a parent process creates an environment for child processes and by default this is the same as the parent's.

It is not possible for any process to modify the environment of any other existing process.